# Getting "Error while proxying to origin" while attempting to reach localhost:8080 using a private network but works fine while on public network

Tags: docker, networking, amazon-ec2

I am running a docker container which is connected to AWS EC2 instance. While attempting to open localhost:8080 I keep getting an error (Error while proxying to origin.). This happens only when I am on a private network. But when I am connected to a public network, I do not get any error. I have added my private and public ip to the security group but it does not solve the issue.

Comment: When you say you have a docker container connected to an EC2 instance, do you mean you have a docker container running inside and EC2 instance, or a docker container running elsewhere which is sending traffic to and from EC2?

Comment: The docker container is running locally and sends traffic to EC2